# Qt qmake doesn't follow source folder structure when using CONFIG += object_parallel_to_source

Tags: qt, config, qt-creator, qmake

When building a project in Qt Creator, I want the (shadowed) build directory to have the same folder structure as my source folder.
This can be done with the (undocumented) statement in the .pro file :

```
CONFIG += object_parallel_to_source
```

The "standard" *.cpp files are compiled and the corresponding *.o files are placed in the correct build folder.
But ... the **moc** and **rcc** place all moc_*.cpp and qrc_*.cpp files in the top level of the build directory, not in the corresponding directory.
What is even worse : qmake creates the complete directory path again within the specified build directory!!

An example will clarify it : say, your source (summarized) is organized like this :

```
/usr/share/myapps/project
  |_ project.pro     <= contains  'CONFIG += object_parallel_to_source'
  |_ mainfolder
  |    |_ main.cpp
  |_ subfolder1
  |    |_ class1_no_QOBJECT.cpp   
  |    |_ class2_with_QOBJECT.cpp
  |_ subfolder2
       |_ class3_no_QOBJECT.cpp
       |_ resources.qrc
```

and the build directory is specified in Qt Creator

```
/usr/share/myapps/build
```

Running qmake and make results in the following build folder structure

```
 /usr/share/myapps/build
      |_ mainfolder
      |    |_ main.o
      |_ subfolder1
      |    |_ class1_no_QOBJECT.o
      |_ subfolder2
      |    |_ class3_no_QOBJECT.o
      |_ moc_class2_with_QOBJECT.cpp    <- should be in subfolder1
      |_ qrc_resources.cpp              <- should be in subfolder2
      |_ usr
           |_ share
               |_ myapps
                    |_build
                       |_ moc_class2_with_QOBJECT.o       <- should be in subfolder1
                       |_ qrc_resources.o                 <- should be in subfolder2
```

Is there a way to prevent this ***doubling*** of the folder structure ?

I'm using Qt 5.9.1 (because this is installed by the hardware supplier - embbeded Linux) on Ubuntu 18.04

EDIT : 
I checked the Makefile which is created by qmake.
The line specifying where to put the Objects should be

```
OBJECTS = /path/to/objects/<filename>.o
```

but is in fact lacking the leading backslash

```
OBJECTS = path/to/objects/<filename>.o
```

This is the root cause for the doubling of the folder structure.

A bug in qmake ?

Comment: Do you actually have sources with same names, is that why you're using `object_parallel_to_source`?  Anyway, seems like it has some bugs, including same one you report... though it was never followed up on:  https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56867  If you don't have conflicting names but want control over where the built objects go, I'd use the dedicated qmake config vars for that (`DESTDIR`, `OBJECTS_DIR`, `MOC_DIR`, `UI_DIR`, `RCC_DIR`, and `OUT_PWD` for the configured build dir).

Comment: @MaximPaperno : at this moment, we don't have sources with same names, as the project is just starting up. But later on, extra developers might/will join this project, and we want to avoid name conflicts. Using the dedicated qmake config variables doesn't work as expected : 
* because we use .pri files, only the last one is used for make
* the folder structure is still copied within the path given in OBJECTS_DIR (see also my edited problem)

Comment: That last part with OBJECTS path does look like a bug maybe. I looked through some generated Makefiles and those paths in OBJECTS seem to be always relative. FWIW here's the code that checks for the "parallel" setting: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/qmake/generators/makefile.cpp.html#_ZN17MakefileGenerator16createObjectListERKi  Do you have anything configured explicitly for `OBJECTS_DIR` in your settings? You don't show any .pri files in your example tree so I'm not sure how those fit in. The `DESTDIR`/etc can be configured in any .pri if you ever run into dupes within a .pro substructure.

Comment: Also from looking at that makefile generation code and the feature [commit notes](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/?id=47df12225918ba82abe35921af19e547717da58b) I don't see anything about it changing generated MOC/UI/RCC locations as you seem to expect. Only objects. And check the last part of the commit notes about "source with a path outside of the root project" -- I'm guessing it thinks the generated moc/qrc files are "outside the root path" since they're not even in the source tree.

Comment: Sorry for not including the .pri files:
I did set the DESTDIR, MOC_DIR in each one, but qmake seems to "remember" only the last one set, so they are NOT relative to each subfolder.

As for the "parallel" setting : in the code you referred to there's this snippet :
` if (QDir::isAbsolutePath(sourceRelativePath))
                sourceRelativePath.remove(0, sourceRelativePath.indexOf(Option::dir_sep) + 1);`
I guess this is the culprit : changing my absolute path to a relative path.